# php remove all node in file xml

Tags: php, xml

I would like to remove all unnecessary nodes from a string

input file:

```
$data="<root>
  <president>
    <handle>0001</handle>
    <title>my title1</title>
    <body_html_>my description 1</body_html_>
    <vendor></vendor>
  </president>
  <president>
    <handle>0002</handle>
    <title>my title 2</title>
    <body_html_>my description 2</body_html_>
    <vendor></vendor>
  </president>
</root>";
```

I would like to remove all the nodes **handle** and **vendor**

i test

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$segarr1 = $doc->President;
$segarr = $segarr1->title;

unset ($segarr[0]);


echo $doc->asXml();
```

delete only the first element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate the children:

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

foreach($doc->children() as $segarr1) {
    unset($segarr1->title);
}

echo $doc->asXml();
```

If you have different children than `president` then you need to check:

```
if($segarr1->getName() == 'president') {
    unset($segarr1->title);
}
```